# Morgan Logger + Express.js: writing file AND showing in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, express

I'm trying to use Morgan with Express.js to write a log file while showing my logs on the console as well.
I'm using this code:

```
var logger = require('morgan');
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream('./access.log', {flags: 'a'});
app.use(logger("dev",{stream: accessLogStream}));
```

But in this way I only get console logs and my access.log file remains empty.

If I do this instead (not specifying "dev"):

```
var logger = require('morgan');
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream('./access.log', {flags: 'a'});
app.use(logger({stream: accessLogStream}));
```

I get the logs on my file but not on the console.

How can I obtain both the log on the console AND on the file?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
at this moment I've found this solution:

```
app.use(logger({format:"[:date[clf]] :method :url :status :response-time ms",stream: {
    write: function(str)
    {
        accessLogStream.write(str);
        console.log(str);
    }
}}));
```

But if you have a better one... you're welcome!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [github](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/issues/51)

```
var logger = require('morgan');

app.use(logger('common', {
    stream: fs.createWriteStream('./access.log', {flags: 'a'})
}));
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

Comment: sorry for not checking the answer

Comment: @Juan the above example *does* `console.log` the info.  `flags: 'a'` opens the file in append mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go brother ! Its almost using everything you provided. 100% working test result.

```
//Logger: production as well as dev. You can set morgan to log differently depending on your environment

 if(app.get("env")=="production") {

        var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/logs/' + "access.log", {flags: 'a'});
        app.use(morgan({stream: accessLogStream}));
    }
     else {
        app.use(morgan("dev")); //log to console on development
    }
```

N.B i have created logs folder and i have access.log file there :).

If you would like to test BOOT YOU NODEJS AS `NODE_ENV=production`.