# How to log issues to a file with NodeJS/ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, error-logging, error-log

I have my ReactJS and NodeJS/ExpressJS project up and running inside an instance. If there were to be a problem/error while the NodeJS is running, is there a way to report/write to a file in a particular directory to keep track of all the server issues?

For example, if it were to crash, it would write the error/issue to a file, so error logging to a file.

Thank you in advance and will accept/upvote answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use morgan to do the magic.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const logger = require('morgan');

app.use(logger('common', {
    stream: fs.createWriteStream('./access.log', {flags: 'a'})
}));

app.use(logger('dev'));
```

It will do both write into a file and show in console.

[Ref to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230365/morgan-logger-express-js-writing-file-and-showing-in-console)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) package with transport to and add it to middleware.

```
  winston.configure({
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'somefile.log' })
    ]
  });
```

Or just use [express-winston](https://github.com/bithavoc/express-winston)